# How to identify which Git Version used in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

We make use of GitHub as enterprise version control system - 'github.org.com" (my organization server URL).

How to find the Git version which is being used by GitHub along with GitHub version?

Comment: I presume "github.org.com" is a typo. GitHub is at github.com .

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't think it is necessarily a typo. It could be a coded representation of the actual GitHub Enterprise server URL, running on premise. We will need to wait for the OP's feedback to know for sure.

Comment: @VonC: I think you're right. A Google search for "github.org.com" produces a number of hits that seem relevant. (Odd, since "org.com" is a real domain.)

Comment: Yes, you are correct @VonC. I mentioned "org" instead of mentioning my organization name. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even the [Meta API](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.17/v3/meta/) would not expose the Git version your GitHub Enterprise server operates on.

This is usually done as a best practice, to avoid exposing [potential security issues linked to the underlying tool (here '`git`')](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-4008/GIT.html) used by a server (here 'GitHub Enterprise')

See for example "[What is the best way to explain (a non-technical person) the risk of leaking version information?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/127638)".

Answer (score -3):

Generally you can see git version by writing this command on git bash "git --version" but for git-app-version you may check this out "https://github.com/csanquer/git-app-version"

Comment: Running `git --version` will only tell you the version *you're* using. The OP is looking for the version that GitHub is using.